# Compile to c++11 in Jgrasp

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, jgrasp

I have Jgrasp set up and running fine with c++. I want to use c++11. I get the following compile error:

```
gift1.cpp:52:24: warning: range-based 'for' loops only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
```

Which I attempt to solve by clicking Settings, compiler settings, workspace. I copied my environment settings "g++ - generic" and renamed it "user: g++ - generic." I then clicked edit. I changed the original compile code:

`g++  %<CY> %<D> -g %<D> -c  -o %<RELE_DEF_BIN_DIR>%<base>.o %<> %<REL_FILE>`

to

```
g++  %<CY> %<D> -g %<D> -c  -o -std=c++11 %<RELE_DEF_BIN_DIR>%<base>.o %<> %<REL_FILE>
```

But it still gives the same error. (I added "-std=c++11".)

Edit: I have changed the string to

```
  g++  -std=c++11 %<CY> %<D> -g %<D> -c  -o %<RELE_DEF_BIN_DIR>%<base>.o %<> %<REL_FILE>
```

but have the same problem. I agree with the comment that this just doesn't appear to be modifying my build commands at all. When I compile, it outputs:

```
jGRASP exec: g++ -g -o gift1.exe gift1.cpp
```

Comment: From your comment, it sounds like the file you're modifying has no effect on your build commands

Comment: Solution was to switch to codeblocks.

Comment: I have the same issue with jGrasp. If you don't have access to Microsoft Visual Studios (Windows version only, Mac version can't use C++11), you can use an online compiler such as repl.it